# Call Marionette onRoute on controller?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have my router as follows -

```
var Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

    appRoutes: {
        'test': 'test'
    },

    onRoute: function(name, path) {
        // this route is being called. This works
        console.log("on route called", name, path);
    }
});
```

And my routerController is as follows -

```
var RouterController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
   test: function() {
       console.log("test route called");
   },

   onRoute: function(name, path) {
     // This onRoute is not being called.
   }
});
```

How can I call the onRoute on the controller rather than the route ? I want to call onRoute on the controller since all my route functions are called on the controller.

Comment: Can't you just use the `controller` property on the router and call it via `this.controller`?

Comment: oops missed that *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

You can access the controller through the options object passed into the router:

```
    var Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

    appRoutes: {
        'test': 'test'
    },

    onRoute: function(name, path, arguments) {
        if (_.isFunction(this.options.controller.onRoute)) {
                this.options.controller.onRoute(name, path, arguments);
            }
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that this will call the onRoute function on the controller every time a route is triggered.